# SKLabelNode automatically has child SKSpriteNode, why?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

When creating an SKLabelNode and printing its children like so:

```
let lbl=SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial")
lbl.text="hello world"
println(lbl.children)
```

this is output:

```
[<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> '<data>' (151 x 26)] position:{-75, -1} size:{151, 26} rotation:0.00]
```

- What is this sprite node?
- And what is the texture named <data>?
- Is this just how SKLabelNode draws itself?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I think  that's how it draws itself.. But maybe someone has more info

Comment: yup, a label node is just a wrapper for a sprite whose texture is generated using font rendering based on the label node's properties (font, size, text, etc)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Do you want to add that as an answer so I can accept it.